# Can i access a variable created in a main() function, in a separate class

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, program-entry-point

Not quite sure how to word this, think i may be being stupid but i am declaring the variable albumInfoArray in my main() function. Is there a way to access this from my mainscreen class. For example the skip_button_clicked() method needs to access the value in the albumInfoArray and it seems this array isnt in its scope.

```
class MainScreen:
    def __init__(self):
        self.main_screen = Tk()
        self.main_screen.geometry ('500x600+100+100')
        self.main_screen.title("Album")
        self.main_screen.configure(background = 'aliceblue')
        self.albumTemp = Image.open("/Users/peacockben/Documents/Ben/Album Guesser/CurrentImage.jpeg")
        self.albumTemp = self.albumTemp.resize((250,250), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        self.album = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.albumTemp)
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.pad1 = Label(self.main_screen, text = " ", bg = "blue", height = 2,width = 13)
        self.pad1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        self.Title = Label(self.main_screen, text = "Albumle",bg ="blue", font = ('',36, 'bold'))
        self.Title.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        self.AlbumImg = Label(self.main_screen, image = self.album, bg = 'aliceblue')
        self.AlbumImg.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
        self.skip_button = Button(self.main_screen,text = "Skip", height = "2",width = "15")
        self.skip_button.grid(row = 3, column = 1)

    def skip_button_clicked(self):
        print(albumInfoArray)


def main():
    albumInfoArray = get_album_info(get_album_index())
    blur_image(albumInfoArray[2],50)
    program = MainScreen()
    program.main_screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: you need to pass the variable when you instantiate the class. You can read more about classes [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html), specifically see 9.3.5

Comment: globals are not a good approach. [This](https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Introduction_to_GUI_Programming.html#tkinter-basics) is a good example on how to do it. See how they pass `Tk`

Answer (score 2):

`albumInfoArray` is in the scope of the main function and shouldn't be accesible outside it.

You could try by declaring it as global:

```
def main():
    global albumInfoArray
    albumInfoArray = get_album_info(get_album_index())
    etc...
```

Comment: I'm not a great fan of declaring global variables. They make difficult to read the code. But it may solve your problem without to many more edits.

Answer (score 0):

A variable if declared inside the main() is accessible only in the main. You cannot even access it within the same class where main() is. You can try declaring the variable as a global variable in the same class as main is.`